# Best way to extract multiple trajectories from uncorelated position data?

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, geometry

TLDR; I have some position data of multiple particles in time and I want to extract the trajectories of each particle!

So, I'm doing some image detection of multiple particles in a fluidized bed (basically a bunch of spheres in a square box that we put liquid through so that the particles start moving like a "fluid" aka a fluidized bed of spherical particles).

The idea being that we put some colored particles in with a bunch of transparent particles, so we can track the trajectory of the tagged particles in motion (the goal is to get the velocities, acceleration, collision rates ...).
[Image example of a tagged particle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsI6t.jpg)

[The data we get from the image processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDN9T.png)
here is the processed position data of a test, as you can see, we detect for each frame the particles (and as you can see, there can be multiple particles detected in the same frame)

the plotted data is shown in the next figure. Mind that we use a single camera to capture the 3 Position components (by using a mirror angled at 45 deg for those who are curious)
[Plotted "intermediate" position data (we already did clean the data a bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfiAC.png)
We can clearly distinguish trajectories, but we also can see that there is still a lot of "noise", and the main problem is that the data is organized in a way that for each frame we detect the particles and store their positions, and redo the same for the next frame, and the problem is that we are not sure if Particles1 for frame X is the same Particle1 that moved in the Frame X+1? You can see the index of each particle for each frame [Particles index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teNFf.png)

My question is; given the plotted data, what is the best way to extract the trajectory of each particle, keeping in mind that I ultimately need the velocities (so I need the temporal component as well)?

I thought about using something similar to the [k-nearest neighbors algorithm][5], but it only classifies them spatially.

Another way I see to solve this is to brute force it and calculate the minimal distance pairs and chain these pairs to form trajectories? But this looks dumb to me, so maybe there is a clever algorithm to do this (traveling salesman problem like algorithm xD ?)

anyway, I would be happy to get any input!

Cheers,

Kamel

Comment: "tracking by detection/association". just assign detections to the nearest existing tracks (or create new tracks). can be made more complicated by giving each track a velocity so you have a better estimate of where it will be. kalman filters are a generalization of that idea.

Comment: you talk about "trees". I don't see that at all. perhaps just delete that word. the description is clear, you have a set of detections per frame, without identity.

Comment: This sounds similar to lagrangian particle tracking which is done in aerodynamics research. KDTrees with nearest neighbors are a good starting point but you have to predict the position in the next time step and search there. https://elib.dlr.de/143984/1/ELIB-Eintrag-2021-JahnT-143984-PaperPublished.pdf

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thankyou for the fast response !, i'm looking into tracking-by-detection and it seems like the way to do it but the first papers i found are very complicated algorithms, i need to find a simpler one but i think this is the a good lead, i also removed the confusing part about the flattened tree !

Comment: ignore all the complicated stuff, including "kdtrees". first prototype: just write a function that gives you the closest point to a query, and be as inefficient as you want. you don't have many points anyway. -- when you've got that working, and something's slow, then you can consider swapping in algorithms that improve the lookup (opencv: FLANN)

Comment: if you want to formulate this as a clustering problem in 4D space (3D + time), meanshift would be an algorithm for that. or DBSCAN as given in the answer below. this formulation can have problems if a point moves quickly. if you have two (true) trajectories passing each other closely and quickly, you will definitely need to estimate velocity too, or else you'll have trouble associating them correctly. simple clustering might also just merge both trajectories into one cluster that's not a single line anymore.

Comment: I ended up using DBScan for clustering the different trajectories, as for now I don't have crossing particles. But thank you for your indications, it would be very helpful if I encounter it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand how precisely You get the measurements. I understand that You have a set of points in 4-D space `(frame ~ time, area, X, Y)` (whatever area is) and I think You need to split these points into sets, where the set corresponds to "a trajectory of one particle", right?

If so, it seems to me that what You are looking for is some sort of clustering in this 4-D space (or maybe 3-D if the `area` does not make sense). `K-means` is not suitable here, my first pick would be something like [DBScan algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I ended up using DBScan to extract the diffirent trajectories as it's quite simple (I am using sklearn's DBScan) for now as i dont have complicated trajectories that cross so it's suficiant !

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy is to predict the positions of the particles from one frame to the next, and match the particles in the new frame to the predicted ones.

The 0th order prediction is to assume that the particles do not move, so you just use the position in the previous frame and nearest neighbor search.

The 1st order prediction would assume that the particles move in a linear motion at constant speed. You can estimate the speed from the last two frames (assuming that you could match them between these frames), and extrapolate to the new one.

A 2nd order prediction would be with accelerations, and so on.

You will face several difficulties, among which

- obtain and maintain correct values of the speeds (it can be beneficial to estimate the speed from several previous frames),
- deal with particles that are not detected in all frames (keep estimating their positions and reject "dubious" matchings),
- ambiguous matchings when two particles cross each other.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I understand the problem more now! As I said in the other comments, I ended up using DBScan Clustering algorithm as for now my trajectories are quite simple. But I will keep this in mind if I need to implement a more robust algorithm, this post will be quite helpful for that! I can't thank you enough for all your kind comments, Cheers guys!